# How to create Isosceles trapezoid?

Tags: anchor-point

1) I create a horizontal rectangle shape.
2) I select the 2 top anchor points using Direct Select, the white arrow (A) while holding shift.
3) If I move them the move the same way forming a parallelogram.

I'd like to know a way for these two top anchors will move mirrored so it form a (tryed alt, etc but couldn't catch it, or if theres a better way to make a trapezoid . 
[image: Shapes for reference]

Comment: Using what software?

Answer (score 7):

For Illustrator:

1. Create a rectangle
2. Select the two top anchor points with the white Direct Selection Tool.
3. Click the Scale Tool [image: scale tool]
4. Drag left and right to scale only the top line. It is automatically constrained to horizontal scaling only.

Alternatively:

3. Select menu "Object > Transform > Scale ..."
4. Type a percentage -- it doesn't matter if you use Uniform or Horizontal, again only the selected anchor points will move horizontally.

This doesn't work with the Transform Each dialog, which always affects the entire object.

The [Online Help](http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/transforming-objects.html#transform_panel_overview) suggests using the Transform panel as a third option, but this, again, seems to always work on the entire object. Which is a pity, because it seems to be the only panel where you can type in a measurement value instead of a percentage.

Answer (score 0):

To make an isosceles trapezoid with two equal lengths/angles in Illustrator:
1. Select the Pen Tool (P). Draw two parallel lines of different lengths. Draw them both perfectly horizontally by holding down Shift.
2. Using the Selection Tool (V), pull the lines apart to the distance of your choice.
 3. Using the Selection Tool (V), drag to select both lines. At the top of the window, in the Control Panel, mouse over the buttons until you find Horizontal Align Center, and click it. The lines should now be centered relative to each other.
4. Finally, you have two choices for adding in the two equal-length lines:
a. With both parallel lines still selected, use the Join command by hitting Ctrl + J **twice** or choosing Object > Path > Join **twice** to create two lines.
b. Using the Pen Tool (P), connect the ends of the two lines on either side.

You should now have a complete isosceles trapezoid, which can rotated and transformed with the Selection Tool (V).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Photoshop, you can draw a square and then use `Transform Path > Perspective`. Drag the top left or top right anchors to adjust accordingly.